# Using SQLBulkCopy - Significantly larger tables in SQL Server 2016 than in SQL Server 2014

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, sqlbulkcopy

I have an application that uses SqlBulkCopy to move data into a set of tables.  It has transpired recently that users that are using SQL2016 are reporting problems with their harddrives being filled with very large databases (that should not be that large).  This problem does not occur in SQL2014.  Upon inspection it appears that running TableDataSizes.sql (script attached) showed large amounts of space in UnusedSpaceKB.

I would like to know if a) There is some bug in SQLServer 2016 or if our use of SQLBulkCopy has "clashed" with a new feature.  I note that there has been some changes to Page Allocation in SQLServer  2016.  In general - What is causing this?

**Steps to Reproduce**
Note – The below describes a situation I am seeing with non-essential information removed. I am not actually storing thousands of timestamps in a database table (the other columns have been removed).

1. Create a database in SQL (mine was called TestDB)
2. Create a table in that DB (using script as below)

   ```
   USE [TestDB]
   GO

   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[2017_11_03_DM_AggregatedPressure_Data]    Script Date: 07/11/2017 10:30:36 ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
       [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
   ```
3. Create an index on that table (using Script as below)

   ```
   USE [TestDB]
   GO

   /****** Object:  Index [2017_11_03_DM_AggregatedPressure_Data_Index]    Script Date: 07/11/2017 10:32:44 ******/
   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [TestTable_Index] ON [dbo].[TestTable]
   (
      [TimeStamp] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
   GO
   ```
4. Start to run records into the table using the code provided below. (This is the code behind for a windows form that simply has a button called btnGo on it and a numericUpDown called nupRecordsToInsert.

   ```
   Public Class Form1

   Private conStr As String = "Integrated Security=true;Persist Security Info=true;Server=.;Database=TestDB;Pooling=True"
   Dim tableName As String = "TestTable"

   Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

       Dim table as DataTable = GetData(nupRecordsToInsert.Value)

       Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conStr)
           conn.Open()
           Using sbc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(conStr, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)

               sbc.DestinationTableName = "[" & tableName & "]"
               sbc.BatchSize = 1000
               sbc.WriteToServer(table)

           End Using
       End Using

       MessageBox.Show($"Records Inserted = {nupRecordsToInsert.Value} into Database - TestDB. Table - {tableName}")
   End Sub

   Private Function GetData(numOfRecordsNeeded As Integer) As DataTable
       Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
       table.Columns.Add("TimeStamp", GetType(DateTime))   

       Dim dtDateTimeToInsert as DateTime = DateTime.Now

       For index As Integer = 1 To numOfRecordsNeeded
           dtDateTimeToInsert = dtDateTimeToInsert.AddSeconds(2)
           table.Rows.Add(dtDateTimeToInsert) 
       Next

       Return table
   End Function
   ```

   End Class
5. At some point around 500 records the number of items in the database table will mean that new records will need to be written onto a new page. At this point interesting this happen as outlined in Actual Results.

**Actual Results**
The databases in SQL2016 are extremely large (this occurs after the first page has been filled and a second one is started).

This can be seen in more detail when

1. Running the below SQL to get an idea of the tablesizes.
   The more records you run into the database the more you see extremely large numbers in the UnusedSpaceKB column.

   ```
   use [TestDB]

   SELECT 
      t.NAME AS TableName,
      s.Name AS SchemaName,
      p.rows AS RowCounts,
      SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
      SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
      (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
   FROM 
      sys.tables t
   INNER JOIN      
      sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
   INNER JOIN 
      sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
   INNER JOIN 
      sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
   WHERE 
     t.NAME = 'TestTable'
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
     AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
   GROUP BY 
     t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
   ORDER BY 
     RowCounts desc
   ```

Output showing large number in UnusedSpaceKB's

[image]

2. Running the below query shows that many pages have been allocated but that only the first one out of every 'set of 8' is used. This leaves the last 7 of every 8 pages unused and thus creates a lot of wasted space.

   ```
    select * from sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations
    (DB_id() , object_id('[dbo].[TestTable]') , NULL , NULL , 'DETAILED')
   ```

The below shows part of the results where the page allocations do not run continously.
[image: Showing spaces in database_page_allocations results]

The databases in SQL2014 do not show this problem
1. When running the appropriate query (as above) we do not see large values in the UnusedSpaceKB column.

2. Running the other query (that queries - dm_db_database_page_allocations) shows many pages have been allocated but each page is being used in sequence. There are no gaps - no blocks of 7 unused pages.

[image: Contiguous page allocations]

**Expected Results**
I would expect SQL2016 to behave like SQL2014 and not create extremely large tables.  In particular I would expect the pages to be allocated contigously and not have 7 page gaps in the allocation.

If anyone has any thought on why I see this difference it would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: Did you check that server FillFactor is the same on both servers? Your CREATE INDEX does NOT specify it explicitly, so server default is used. P.S. Why don't you create your index AFTER your BulkCopy? As you do it now, you'll never have minimal logging

Comment: You're using bulk copy in almost the least efficient way possible -- you have a clustered index on the table, a batch size of 1000 and are using row locks rather than table locks. You'll still get streamed data, but the operation itself will be fully logged. However, that in itself should not be changed from SQL Server 2014. Are the recovery models the same in both cases? Have any custom trace flags been applied? (Like trace flag 610, which enables minimal logging for bulk inserts on tables with clustered indexes)?

Comment: What are the autogrowth settings for the databases? How much data is being moved? What does `too large` even mean? The steps in this question are too vague to reproduce any problem

Comment: Just for a quick check, increase your BatchSize to 10000 or similar.

Comment: Based on Panagiotis comment. Have provided some pictures of the outputs to further explain how the difference in size between the two databases manifests itself.  You should be able to see clearly that in SQL2014 page allocations run contigously and that in SQL2016 version the page allocations leave many pages unused.  It is this I believe that is causing the difference in table sizes, but I have no idea why.

Comment: One extent is 8 pages. It looks like each page allocation is done from a new extent. [Likely related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/). As has already been suggested, try increasing your batch size (the article also mentions TF 692 as a workaround if you can't). (Also, it's nice to know TF 610 is no longer required in SQL Server 2016 to get minimally-logged bulk inserts on clustered indexes.)

Comment: Note that bulk insert is and will always be optimized for *bulk* inserts -- for sufficiently small batches, you may consider switching to regular inserts in a transaction, which will not be much slower.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thanks very much for your help here.  This is very much on the lines that I need to investigate.  I will get stuck into this and see what I can find.  Again - thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [use trace flag 692](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/):

> If for any reason, you cannot change the batchsize or if you are not seeing an improved data load performance with default minimal logging behavior, you can disable fast inserts behavior in SQL Server 2016 using trace flag 692 (...). We do not anticipate under normal circumstances this trace flag will be required for customers.